# Height of element is ignored if parent is flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a header with a height set but it's ignored and it shrinks down to whatever the content height is. (see Sample 1)

I know that happens because the *parent container* (the `body` in the examples) has `display: flex` and `flex-grow: column`. But I need that because in other scenarios I want one of the children to `flex-grow: 1` and fill all remaining height of the viewport. (see Sample 2)

Also, that only happens if the page is taller than the viewport (in other words, if the *parent container* with `display: flex` and `flex-grow: column` has a vertical scrollbar).

[Sample 1](https://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/BEgoLZ) | 
[Sample 2](https://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/MYXENq)

Why does that happen?

It can be fixed if I use `min-height` instead...but why is the height ignored?

Another thing: on the work I'm doing (not in the examples) some absolute positioned elements get mispositioned if the parent is `display: flex` and `flex-grow: column` so that raises me another question: is it a good practice to have your whole application wrapped by a parent with `display: flex` and `flex-grow: column`?

Comment: you need to consider `flex-shrink`

Comment: I removed `height:100%` from `body`. https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/YMowzx